# QCA Library for windows

Tags: windows, qt, encryption, compilation

I am compiling the QCA Library for windows and using the steps from INSTALL File for for configure I am using the following command in windows console:

```
configure.exe --qtdir=C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw
```

The response is:

```
Configuring Qt Cryptographic Architecture (QCA) ...

Reason: There was an error compiling 'conf'.  See conf.log for details.
```

I am trying to compile using Qt in windows directly and shows the following error:

```
-I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\mlock.o ..\..\Encryption-QCA\src\botantools\botan\ml_win32\mlock.cpp
In file included from c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/objbase.h:73,
                 from c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/ole2.h:9,
                 from c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/windows.h:114,
                 from ..\..\Encryption-QCA\src\botantools\botan\ml_win32\mlock.cpp:37:
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/objidl.h:95: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/AlejoLina/Documents/Alejandro/Compacta/SE-HA_Tool/Encryption-QCA-build-desktop/src'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/AlejoLina/Documents/Alejandro/Compacta/SE-HA_Tool/Encryption-QCA-build-desktop/src'
mingw32-make[2]: *** [release/mlock.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-make_default] Error 2
The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project qca (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the configure was that the executable doesnt find the windows make (mingw-make).

The solution is to put the right path to the envinronment variables (qt and mingw bin path).

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure that this is your problem but you may want to try using the `make` that is available with [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys). I've always had better success with it. From [MinGW's own FAQ](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ#faq-mingw32-make.exe)..

> The "native" (i.e.: MSVCRT dependent)
>   port of make is lacking in some
>   functionality and has modified
>   functionality due to the lack of POSIX
>   on Win32.